# Create model (instance) Abstract Model

Tags: model, abstract, pyomo

I am using Pyomo 4.4.1 (VOTD) (CPython 2.7.12) and I am in an Abstract Model. If I use: `instance = model.create('datos.dat')`

I get:

```
WARNING: DEPRECATION WARNING: the Model.create() method is deprecated.  Call
        Model.create_instance() to create a concrete instance from an abstract
        model.  You do not need to call Model.create() for a concrete model.
Model unknown
```

But it returns the good solution!

I change this line, writing:  `Model.create_instance(datos.dat)` but I get an Error:

```
results = opt.solve(instance)
NameError: name 'instance' is not defined
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks, Maria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct: a "deprecation warning" is a warning that a method, attribute, or function is changing and the old way will be removed in a future release.  So, for the time being, the old method (in this case, `create()` still works as it always has, but you should start working to change your models to use the new interface (in this case `create_instance()`) so that your models will continue to work in future releases.

That said, you still need to assign the result from `create()` or `create_instance()` to a variable that you can later pass to the solver.  So, you would want something like:

```
instance = model.create_instance('datos.dat')
opt = SolverFactory('cbc')
solver_results = opt.solve(instance)
```

These are just Python variables, so you could just as easily done

```
a = model.create_instance('datos.dat')
b = SolverFactory('cbc')
c = b.solve(a)
```

Pyomo examples typically use `instance`, `opt` (or `solver`), and `results` to help with making the examples more clear.